# how can I do paypal card present(card swipe) payments using rest api in c#?

Tags: paypal, payment-gateway, paypal-rest-sdk

How can I do the paypal card present payment in paypal as we use track2data in authorize.net? We are using C# paypal rest API should I need to use payflow link or pro for that or anything else?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take a look on Payflow implementation using the Swipe Data :

https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/payflow/integration-guide/#submitting-card-present---swipe---transactions